# Variadic template pointer to member function declaration/usage issues

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

```
// This compiles and runs properly
using MemPtr = Entity&(OBFactory::*)(const Vec2i&, float);
void test(MemPtr mptr, const Vec2i& p, float d)
{
    (getFactory().*mptr)(p, d);
}

//  "no matching function for call to `test`, 
//  failed candidate template argument deduction"
template<typename... A> using MemPtr = Entity&(OBFactory::*)(A...);
template<typename... A> void test(MemPtr<A...> mptr, const Vec2i& p, float d)
{
    (getFactory().*mptr)(p, d);
}

...

// I call both versions with
test(&OBFactory::func, Vec2i{0, 0}, 0.f);
```

Why doesn't the variadic template version work? Am I missing some forwarding?

Comment: How do you call the second version of `test()`?

Comment: @Oberon: updated main question

Comment: How many `func` does `OBFactory` has ? If more than one, then there is an ambiguity as to which choose. If possible, could you please provide a minimal *complete* program for example on `ideone` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could serve as an example of what is happening in your code:

```
struct A
{
    // there are multiple overloads for func (or a template?)
    void func(double) {}
    void func(int) {}
};

//using MemPtr = void(A::*)(double);
//void test(MemPtr mptr, double d)
//{
//    (A().*mptr)(d);
//}

template<typename... As> using MemPtr = void(A::*)(As...);
template<typename... As> void test(MemPtr<As...> mptr, double d)
{
    (A().*mptr)(d);
}

int main()
{
    // test(&A::func, 0.); // line X
    test(static_cast<void(A::*)(double)>(&A::func), 0.); // line Y
}
```

The problem in line X is that you use `&A::func` and the compiler now needs to deduce the `As...` - which it can't. Line Y fixes that by explicitly casting it to the correct overload.

If you use the first version of `test` (the one commented out above), `test`'s signature contains the necessary type already (no deduction needed) and the compiler knows how to cast (in this case this means *select*) the correct overload for `func`.